# php package stand-alone philo/laravel-blade giving blank screen

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to use this php package [here](https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade) with php 7.0.33 but its neither giving any error nor working. its just giving a blank screen. Below is my code. How to debug ?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Philo\Blade\Blade;

$views = __DIR__ . '/views';
$cache = __DIR__ . '/cache';

$blade = new Blade($views, $cache);
echo $blade->view()->make('hello')->render();
```

Comment: Did you create the `views` and `cache` folders?

Comment: @CaddyDZ yes I did and also I gave all permissions. Can you please test, is that package working ok for you?

Comment: I did, and answered accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a semicolon here

```php
error_reporting(E_ALL); <-- Missing
```

Which is why it doesn't show anything

Then make sure to have a `hello.blade.php` file in your `views` folder structured as HTML

[image: Directory Structure]

`views/hello.blade.php`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello, World!
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps